# How to output only the whole passage [Google Cloud Vision API, document_text_detection]

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-vision

I try Google Cloud Vision API's `document_text_detection`. It works really well in Japanese, but I have a problem. The response contains both the whole passage and partial passages with line breaks. I only need the whole passage.

This is the response.

```
Google keep の画像 テキスト化
画像文字認識で手書き文字をどこ
までテキスト化が出来るのかをテスト。
Google keep OCR機能がとれた
け使えるかを確認
この手書き文書を認献してiPhone
のGoogle keepでテキスト化して
Macで編集をするのにどれだけ
出来るかも確認する。

Google
keep
の画像
テキスト化
画像文字認識で手書き文字をどこ
までテキスト化が出来るのかをテスト
。
Google
keep
OCR機能がとれた
け使えるかを確認
この手書き文書を認献してiPhone
のGoogle
keepでテキスト化して
Macで編集をするのにどれだけ
出来るかも確認する
。
```

This is my python code.

```
import io
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="credentials.json"
"""Detects text in the file."""
from google.cloud import vision
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
directory = 'resources/'
files = os.listdir(directory)

for i in files:
    with io.open(directory+i, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = vision.types.Image(content=content)

    response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)
    texts = response.text_annotations

    for text in texts:
        print('{}'.format(text.description))
```

I read API reference (https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageResponse#TextAnnotation)  and came up with the idea to use `response.full_text_annotation` instead of `response.text_annotations`.

```
image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)
texts = response.full_text_annotation
print('{}'.format(text))
```

But I got a error message.

```
File "/home/kazu/language/ocr.py", line 21, in <module> print('{}'.format(text))
NameError: name 'text' is not defined
```

Could you give me any information or suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Sincerely, Kazu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a typo. You named your variable "texts", but tried to use variable "text".

Comment: Oh my god. I made a terrible mistake. Thank you very much @Brendan . I have tried couple of times and `image = vision.types.Image(content=content) response = client.document_text_detection(image=image) texts = response.full_text_annotation.text print('{}'.format(texts))` is the answer for me.